# Time series data visualization using JSON

Tags: json, d3.js, charts, chart.js, data-visualization

Iam using https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json to retrieve data to display in a timeseries chart for a specific country say, for example South Africa.

```
<script>
fetch("https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data["South Africa"].forEach(({ date, confirmed, recovered, deaths }) =>
      console.log(`${date} active cases: ${confirmed - recovered - deaths}`)



    );
  });
</script>
```

How do I go about creating a chart time series that shows the active cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below runnable code snippet illustrates how this can be done.

```js
let dates = [];
let confirmed = [];
let recovered = [];
let deaths = [];

fetch("https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data=> {
    data["South Africa"].forEach(o => {
      dates.push(o.date);
      confirmed.push(o.confirmed);
      recovered.push(o.recovered);
      deaths.push(o.deaths);
    })
    new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: dates,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Confirmed',
            borderColor: 'orange',
            backgroundColor: 'orange',
            fill: 'false',
            data: confirmed
          },
          {
            label: 'Recovered',
            borderColor: 'green',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            fill: 'false',
            data: recovered
          },
          {
            label: 'Deaths',
            borderColor: 'red',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            fill: 'false',
            data: deaths
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Covid-19 / South Africa'
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate @uminder it worked. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Yes Sir. I was wondering if it is possible to filter to today date? such that data only for today or current date is displayed

Comment: Sure it is possible. A bar chart may be a good solution to do this. Give it a try and in case you're facing problems, post a new question, showing your code and describing the new issue.